# Preserve LAST file in set of matches with fdupes (default deletes FIRST file)

Tags: linux, bash, duplicates

Using the following bash command, fdupes consistently puts the file that I want to preserve in the LAST position within each set:

```
fdupes --order=name ./"Camera Roll" > ~/Desktop/Temp/temp.txt
```

AFAIK, fdupes only has a built-in option to preserve the FIRST file in a set, but not the last.

I tried using the "-i" flag, but I got the same ordering. I'm guessing that the ordering by names occurs AFTER the reverse sorting so that the reverse sorting is essentially nullified:

```
fdupes -i --order=name ./"Camera Roll" > ~/Desktop/Temp/temp.txt
```

Same result putting the "-i" flag second:

```
fdupes --order=name -i ./"Camera Roll" > ~/Desktop/Temp/temp.txt
```

Can anyone please recommend a way to preserve the LAST file in each set of dups and delete the rest?

FYI, some of the sets of dups have more than 2 files.

Thanks!

UPDATE: This issue was resolved after upgrading to the latest version of fdupes. See comments for details.

Comment: My tests work as expected. `fdupes --order=name` lists the groups sorted by name in ascending order, `fdupes -i --order=name` lists the groups sorted by name in descending order. Might be of interest: `-i` reversed both the ordering of the groups and the ordering within the groups. Using fdupes 2.1.2

Comment: Thank you! 

I was running version 1.6.1 before, which is apparently the latest version available from the Ubuntu repo. I upgraded to version 2.1.2 from GitHub, and now the "-i" tag works as expected.

https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes/releases